# knockout.js Computed observable called twice in Internet Explorer

Tags: knockout.js

Please see the simple example below; a text box that is bound to a computed observable. My problem is that IE calls the **write** method twice when the text box is updated. Firefox and other browsers do not appear to have this problem. I have observed this issue in IE 7 & 8.

First of all, am I doing something wrong? If not, what is the recommended approach to deal with it?

```
<script>
    var viewModel = {
        myTestVar: "aaa"
    };

    viewModel.myTest = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return viewModel.myTestVar;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            alert(value);
            viewModel.myTestVar = value;
        },
        owner: viewModel
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input data-bind="value:myTest",type="text" style="width:150px;" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` binding has a special section for dealing with auto-complete in Internet Explorer. This will often cause two writes. You can turn it off if you don't care about auto-complete by adding an attribute to the `input`:

```
<input data-bind="value:myTest" type="text" style="width:150px;" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The write method is now called only once.

Comment: This did not work for me in IE 10 with IE9 standards document mode. I stepped through the code in the KO debug version, and `element.autocomplete` was `undefined` inside the `value` binding check, causing the double event handlers to be registered. Do you know if there is an open issue for this or if it has been addressed?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in IE10 compatibility mode. I don't know of any open issue about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
write: function (value) {
    if(value != viewModel.myTestVar) {
        alert(value);
        viewModel.myTestVar = value;
    }
}
```

Since viewModel.myTestVar is not an observable, I do not have a good idea why the write is called two times, but the check should prevent the actual multiple write.